# Why is numpy giving the wrong answer to this matrix inverse?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm very new to using Python and numpy, and for some reason it can't seem to give a correct answer to this matrix inverse. Now it's just this specific matrix, as far as I can tell, as when I use various different random matrices, all functions as normal.

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.linalg.inv(a)
print(b)
```

and the console output is:

```
[[ 3.15251974e+15 -6.30503948e+15  3.15251974e+15]
 [-6.30503948e+15  1.26100790e+16 -6.30503948e+15]
 [ 3.15251974e+15 -6.30503948e+15  3.15251974e+15]]
```

All massive numbers, that are false answers. The correct answers are:

```
[[-11/12, 1/3, 1/12],[-1/6,1/3,-1/6,],[3/4,-1/3,1/12]]
```

[image]

Furthermore, if I try to determine what the `np.dot(a,b)` is, which should be (when rounded):

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [-0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

But I get:

```
[[ 0.   1.  -0.5]
 [ 0.   2.  -1. ]
 [ 0.   3.   2.5]]
```

And when I try these calculations on ANY (as far as I can tell, I've tried a dozen random ones) other matrix set, all the answers work out correct. I've also opened multiple new `.ipynb` files and it still doesn't function properly. So what's going on here, and how can I fix it/make sure it doesn't act this way with any other matrix set?

Comment: first of all, the code in he question does not work. so please correct this. Also, please advise what you are expecting as a result.   [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @D.L I just tried it [here](https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/retro/notebooks/?path=notebooks/Intro.ipynb) and I can reproduce the problem with exactly the code shown.

Comment: Strange, I get a "singular matrix" error when I try to run this code.

Comment: the code throws a `LinAlgError "Singular matrix" error` likely because the 3x3 matrix you are trying to invert is **singular** - meaning it does not have an inverse.

Comment: @MosheKatz,  the link that you sent does not open anything, so i cannot verify.  But you can verify that the determinant = 0 yourself.  if `matrix = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]` then `det(matrix) = a(ei - fh) - b(di - fg) + c(dh - eg)`

Comment: By the way, the title of the question is wrong, it is not jupyter notebook giving this result, but numpy.

Answer (score 2):

it appears as thought the code has an error and that the determinant of the matrix = 0 and therefore it does not have an inverse.

so i modified the last number in the numpy array of the 3x3 matrix (from a 9 to an 8) and this works.

You would need to add a check to proceed.

The check could look like this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 8]])
det = np.linalg.det(a)
if det == 0:
    print('determinant = 0. there is no inverse.')
else:
    b = np.linalg.inv(a) 
    print(b)
```

which would return this:

```
[[-2.66666667  2.66666667 -1.        ]
 [ 3.33333333 -4.33333333  2.        ]
 [-1.          2.         -1.        ]]
```

Beyond the above, it would be helpful if you added what you would expect as the output of the inverse compared to what python (numpy) is producing....

Comment: I did, this matrix DOES have an inverse, at least according to any online calculator I plug it into. This is the output I SHOULD be getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvSJi.png

Comment: @Hummingbee No it doesn't, and no it isn't

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well.

It seems that the matrix you provided cannot be inverted, which is why you're getting unexpected results. The matrix given has a determinant of 0, which means it is singular and does not have an inverse.

A square matrix can only be inverted if its determinant is not zero. Thus your error.

If you try to compute the inverse of a singular matrix using numpy's np.linalg.inv function, it may still give you a result, but it won't be the correct inverse. Instead, it will provide a pseudo-inverse, which can result in large numbers like the ones you observed in your output.

To make sure that the matrix you want to invert is non-singular, you can calculate its determinant and check that it is not zero before attempting to find the inverse. Here's an example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
det = np.linalg.det(a)
if det != 0:
    b = np.linalg.inv(a)
    print(b)
else:
    print("The matrix is singular and does not have an inverse.")
```

This code checks if the determinant of a matrix is non-zero. If it is, it calculates the inverse using np.linalg.inv. If the determinant is zero, it prints a message saying the matrix is singular. Additionally, please note that the correct inverse you provided is for a modified version of the original matrix, which is invertible.

Cheers,
theClawsmos

P.S. I used ChatGPT to simplify my terms, so please comment if it helps.

Comment: you just repeated the answer that i posted 5 minutes ago (with very similar points) !!   ....well at least i have some support.

Comment: oops sorry XD oh well. at least we agree 

Comment: This matrix DOES have an inverse, at least according to any online calculator I plug it into. This is the output I SHOULD be getting: i.stack.imgur.com/tvSJi.png

Comment: @Hummingbee, it does not and the reason for this is that the determinant = 0. Also, putting this into `numpy.linalg.inv` which is reasonably standard gives this error: `LinAlgError: Singular matrix`...  so `numpy` is telling you the same as other users.  If it does have an inverse, then what is it please ?

Comment: [[-11/12, 1/3, 1/12],[-1/6,1/3,-1/6,],[3/4,-1/3,1/12]]

Comment: _I used ChatGPT to simplify my terms, so please comment if it helps_ - whether it does or not, [All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: Anyway, this is wrong. _it will provide a pseudo-inverse_ is simply not true. The Moore-Penrose-like pseudoinverse is only available from the `pinv` routine; see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html.

Answer (score 0):

@D.L is correct, and whatever online calculator you've used is not. Observe:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
])
b = np.array([
    [-11/12,  1/3, 1/12],
    [  -1/6,  1/3, -1/6],
    [   3/4, -1/3, 1/12],
])
print((b@a).round(3))
print((a@b).round(3))
```

```
[[ 1.   0.5 -0. ]
 [-0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.5  1. ]]

[[ 1.  0. -0.]
 [ 0.  1. -0.]
 [-1.  2. -0.]]
```

If you *did* have a correct inverse, both of those products should be identities, and they aren't. Moreover, current versions of Numpy when given an exact version of your input will throw

```
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

For giggles, let's invert your inverse to find out what you *actually* entered:

```
[[1. 2. 3.]
 [4. 5. 6.]
 [7. 2. 9.]]
```

Spot the difference!